# Storing frequent keys in a map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Imagine that I am calculating a double type score for some large number of strings (i.e. 100 millions), and I want to have a sort of caching effect to re-use what I have computed so far whenever it is necessary. Now, the smart way to do this is to store those frequent strings and their scores in the map, to reduce the memory usage. Is there any standard solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at ``std::map``, it is associative array where you can use ``std::string`` as key and ``double`` as value.

Comment: Is it okay for your cache to grow without bound, or are you looking for more of an LRU solution (i.e. where after the cache reaches a given maximum size, cache entries that haven't been used recently get disposed of in order to keep it from growing any larger)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what you just mentioned ,LRU solution, sounds like what I am looking for.

Comment: @user3639557 LRU's can be implemented easily in C++ on top of a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and a `std::list`... the map provides fast lookup to a list node when there's a hit, then that list node is snipped out and moved to the front of the list.  On a cache miss you push to the front of the list and add to the map, while dropping the last item from the list and map.  You'll probably find some examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Bloom Filters along with Maps or Hashmaps

I am assuming as you mention that there are 100's of millions of strings not all of them might be present on disk.

What i would suggest is a two layer hierarchy as follows:

Create a hashmap which is of the following format:

```
std::map<std::string, double> map;
```

This could contain the last 500 referenced entries. You can have a eviction policy based on TTL if you use a map.

If you want a eviction policy based on least recently used, you will have tweak the datastructure a little bit

```
std::map<std::string, cached_data> map;

struct cached_data
{
   double value;
   int times_accessed;         //Number of times it has been accessed.
}
```

Insertion will become slightly complicated.

Now what do we do when cache access fails, you don't want to read the disk unnecessarily if you actually don't have the data. For that you can use a bloomfilter. Bloom filter will tell you the probability of presence of your data, hence preventing the disk read.

I would suggest stories the large number of strings on disk in a sorted manner with index consisting of the Keys --> Disk address mapping.

Answer largely inspired by Cassandra